# strcmp misbehave with 2 same strings

Tags: c, strcmp

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  char s1[50], s2[50];

  printf("write s1:\n");
  fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);

  printf("s2:\n");
  fgets(s2, sizeof(s2), stdin);

  printf("The concatenation of the two strings: %s\n", strcat(s1, s2));

  if( strcmp(s2, s1) < 0 ) {
    printf("s2 is shorter than s1.\n");
  } else if( strcmp(s2, s1) > 0 ) {
    printf("s2 is longer than s1.\n");
  } else {
    printf("strings are equal.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I write 2 same strings like abc or whatever, strcmp return "s2 is shorter than s1."

Is that the normal output or have I done anything wrong? If so, where?

Or strcat makes the string not equal? Can anything be done about this?

Thank you

Comment: see [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) section return value. the value returned only relates to the first difference ( nothing todo with overall length comparison ). if you want to compare string lengths use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)..

Comment: yes. strcmp return a non-zero number when strcat is in the code. when I comment it, then strcmp return 0

Comment: s1 = "abcabc" and s2 = "abc", comparison makes s2 is shorter than s1.

Comment: so the code is ok and that should be the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing

```
 strcat(s1, s2)
```

before comparing. Which will modify string `s1` so strings will not be equal

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a strcat before doing doing strcmp. strcat would concatenate s2 to s1

Answer (score 1):

`Strcmp` compares the strings according to the value of their contents (similar to the dictionary order, if you like, but not exactly that) not according to their length.

For example: "abc" > "abb"

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
    printf("The concatenation of the two strings: %s\n", strcat(s1, s2));
```

with

```
    printf("The two strings are: '%s' and '%s' and their concatenation: '%s'\n",
    s1, s2, strcat(s1, s2));
```

Then read a description of `strcat`.

If that doesn't help, replace `%s` sequences with `%p`. (Possibly you'll have to read a description of the `%p` format specifier in the `printf` documentation.)